# Invalid SQLFORM submit generates ticket instead of showing errors on form

Tags: python, web2py

Here is my `db.py`:

```
db.define_table('antenna_details',
                Field('antenna_name',required=True),
                Field('model_name',required=True),
                Field('project_name',required=True),
                Field('frequency_band',required=True),
                Field('polarization',required=True),
                Field('aperture_size',required=True),
                Field('fixer_availability',required=True),
                Field('weight',required=True),
                Field('material',required=True),
                Field('email_id',required=True,unique=True,requires=[IS_NOT_IN_DB]),
                Field('subject',type='text',required=True),
                Field('attached',type='upload', label="""
                    Antenna/feed Geometry
                    Electrical specification
                    Attach Simulated data in predicted form
                """)
)

db.antenna_details.email_id.requires=[IS_EMAIL(),IS_NOT_EMPTY()]
db.antenna_details.attached.requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.antenna_details.subject.rquires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.antenna_details.material.requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.antenna_details.weight.requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.antenna_details.fixer_availability.requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.antenna_details.aperture_size.requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.antenna_details.polarization.requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.antenna_details.frequency_band.requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.antenna_details.project_name.requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()
db.antenna_details.model_name.requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()
```

And Here is my default.py index action:

```
def index():
    """
    example action using the internationalization operator T and flash
    rendered by views/default/index.html or views/generic.html

    if you need a simple wiki simply replace the two lines below with:
    return auth.wiki()
    """
    # response.flash = T("Hello World")
    # return dict(message=T('Welcome to web2py!'))

    form = SQLFORM(db.antenna_details).process()

    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash = 'your data is posted'

    return dict(form=form)
```

Now when I hit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Test/default`, I get the form and when I submit it with an email id that already exists in the database, I get a ticket that says this:

```
<class 'sqlite3.IntegrityError'> column email_id is not unique
```

There are other constraints as well in the model(specifically IS_NOT_EMPTY()) but when this constraint is violated, the app simply redirects user back to the form and shows error in red. But for the duplicate email, it throws a ticket.

Why is it happening and what needs to be done so that on violation of IS_NOT_IN_DB constraint on email, it should redirect back to the form and show error in red near the email field similar to what happens with violation of IS_NOT_EMPTY constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                Field('email_id',required=True,unique=True,requires=[IS_NOT_IN_DB]),
...
db.antenna_details.email_id.requires=[IS_EMAIL(),IS_NOT_EMPTY()]
```

There are two problems. First, your `IS_NOT_IN_DB` validator is incorrect -- it should be something like `IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'antenna_details.email_id')`.

Second, after you set the `requires` attribute of the `email_id` field to `IS_NOT_IN_DB` in the field definition, you then completely overwrite it with new validators, which do not include `IS_NOT_IN_DB`. You should either append the additional validators or define them all in once place. (For that matter, you can move all of your validator assignments into the field definitions rather than putting them all after the table definition.)

Comment: Thanks for clarification . Is there a difference between defining validators in field definition and after table definitions(i.e. inside the Field vs outside the table like db.antenna_details.email_id.requires...)? And when we should use either?

Comment: The only difference is that if you are using the [`DAL(..., lazy_tables=True)` option](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#markmin_lazy_tables), the latter approach removes the benefit of lazy tables, as `db.mytable.myfield.requires` forces the table to be defined immediately (the first time you call `db.mytable`, the table is fully defined if it was a lazy table). Otherwise, it is just a matter of personal preference. In some cases, you need to set the `requires` attribute separately (e.g. if you need to override the default validator in a controller).